# Change String containing ' ,to TitleCase

Tags: javascript, regex

Im able to change  a normal string to title case using this.

```
return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
```

Im not sure how to make a string like this to title case,

```
maureen o'hara -> Maureen O'Hara
maureen macnamee -> Maureen MacNamee
Maureen mctavis ->Maureen McTavis
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2w8kejdq/). `console.log('maurEEN o\'hARA'.replace(/\b(\w)(\w*)/g, function (m, grp1, grp2) {
    return grp1.toUpperCase() + grp2.toLowerCase();
}));`

Comment: thanks, that worked what if the surname had macnamee or mc?

Comment: Is that a requirement? Please add the sample input to the question with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
function nameToTC(input) {
  return input.replace(/\b(ma?c)?(\w)(\w*)/ig, function (m, grp1, grp2, grp3) {
    if (grp1) {
        return grp1.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + grp1.substr(1).toLowerCase() + grp2.toUpperCase() + grp3.toLowerCase();
    }
    else {
        return grp2.toUpperCase() + grp3.toLowerCase();
    }
  });
}
console.log(nameToTC('maureen o\'hara'));
console.log(nameToTC('maureen macnamee'));
console.log(nameToTC('Maureen mctavis'));
```

Result:

```
Maureen O'Hara
Maureen MacNamee
Maureen McTavis
```

The regex - `\b(ma?c)?(\w)(\w*)` - matches a word boundary first with `\b`, then optionally matches and captures into Group 1 `mac` or `Mc`, etc. with `(ma?c)?`, then matches and captures into Group 2 one alphanumeric symbol (`(\w)`) and then matches and captures into Group 3 0 or more final alphanumeric characters belonging to the current word (with `(\w*)`).

Inside the callback function, we check if Group 1 is set, if it is, we capitalize the `mc` or `mac` and then the rest. If Group 1 is not set, we do not handle that part and only capitalize Group 2.

Answer (score 1):

Regex are fun, but if you want to try a more human readable approach try with this:

```
    function toTitleCase(str)
    {
        return str.replace(/\w+/g, function(txt){
            if (txt.substr(0,2) === "mc") return "Mc" + txt.charAt(2).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(3).toLowerCase();
            else if (txt.substr(0,3) === "mac") return "Mac" + txt.charAt(3).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(4).toLowerCase();
            return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        });
    }
```

It should work and is "easier" to extend.